# ProcessBuilder: Start .jar in java package

Tags: java, jar, package, processbuilder, getresource

I try to execute an external jar in my java application. The .jar is in my java-package ("gui").
I tried:

```
            String filepath = this.getClass().getResource("ServerRSS.jar").getPath();
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", filepath);
```

System.out.println(filepath); results in:

```
/C:/Users/hox/workspace/PraktikumProg/bin/gui/ServerRSS.jar
```

My programm doesn't start. Could the problem be the slash before the C: ?

EDIT: 
The solution was:

```
URL filepath = this.getClass().getResource("ServerRSS.jar");
ProcessBuilder pb;
pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", new File(filepath.toURI()).toString());
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Please note that I enhanced my answer. Please give some feedback if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get your command working ... simply on the command line.

And only then try to run it from within Java using a ProcessBuilder.

Simple answer is probably: to use **-jar** when invoking java.

```
java someJar.jar
```

does not work!

And yes, that slash matters big time. You simply want a fully correct file path there.

Finally: are you really sure you want to start a new JVM in order to run a main method in some class? You see, you could do that within your current JVM -  without the additional performance and complexity cost of using a second JVM!